# What does this Chinese graffiti from The Sand Pebbles mean?

Tags: dialogue, the-sand-pebbles

Late in the movie *The Sand Pebbles*, Steve McQueen is about to share his backstory with Candice Bergen, and there is this graffiti in the background:

[image: steve mcqueen in the sand pebbles]

Just idle curiosity on my part, I happened to pause my DVR at this scene and was curious if the graffiti was placed there intentionally for this shot.

Comment: I think it says 木子四. What **that** is, I'm not sure.

Comment: It literally means 'tree', 'little/child', 'four' but this makes little sense

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually, it appears to say **李四**, not  木子四 as commentators above have said. (the 木 and 子 are connected at the bottom and top, respectively).

**李四**, pronounced Li Si, means "John Doe", or "Anonymous".

It's part of a idiom that goes 張三, 李四, 王五 . Kind of like English's "Tom, Dick and Harry". 張, 李, 王 (Chang/Zhang, Li/Lee, and Wang/Wong) are three very common Chinese last names. 三,四, 五 are 3, 4, and 5. So the phrase is "Chang number 3, Li number 4, and Wang number 5"

Comment: You are probably correct but normally such logograms are spaced such that the character width/height is uniform to avoid such confusion, whoever wrote this possibly is not a native speaker or did this in a messy manner, I'm Chinese so this is what I think

Comment: So am I. My handwriting sucks though, so my Chinese characters can be out of proportion just like above. The lack of spacing between the 木 and 子 suggests that it is one character, where there is noticeable space between   the 子 and 四.

Comment: @EdChum how neatly could you write if carving into stone without the proper tools? Considering that, I think this is pretty good.